# how to click this outer div element(or any other span inside it) in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I wish to click on this div, which further contains many spans in it. The xpath of the outer div keeps on changing everytime the page is loaded. So Is there any other way(apart from xpath) to click this div?

I have tried-

```
Driver().findElement(By.cssSelector(".z3tile.z3activeTile.z3-tile-medium")).click();
```

But this didn't work.

Will appreciate if somebody can suggest some other way.

```html
<div class="z3tile z3activeTile z3-tile-medium"
bo-style="{'backgroundColor': getTileBackgroundColor(app) }"
bo-class="'z3-tile-'+preferences._View._TileSize"
onkeypress="audience(app._Code);openApp(event,
$(this).prev('div').attr('data-attr-param_keypress_url'),
$(this).prev('div').attr('title'),
$(this).prev('div').attr('data-attr-param_keypress_name'),
$(this).prev('div').attr('data-attr-param_keypress_ticket'),
$(this).prev('div').attr('bo-attr-param_keypress_langue'),
$(this).prev('div').attr('data-attr-param_keypress_paramBrowser'))"
ng-click="audience(app._Code);openApplication(app._Url, app._Source,
app._Name, app._Ticket, preferences._Langue, app._ParamBrowser)"
ng-hide="app._Search" role="link" tabindex="3" indexapp="4"
idgroup="-1" display-app-tooltip="" style="background-color: rgb(246,
131, 0);" data-original-title="" title="">

<span class="ng-binding z3appTitle-medium" type="text"
bo-class="'z3appTitle-'+preferences._View._TileSize"
bo-style="{'color': DefaultTitleColor + ' !important',
'backgroundColor':
getTitleTileBackgroundColor(getTileBackgroundColor(app))}"
ng-bind="app._ShortName" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(144, 77, 0);">SAV2000</span>

<span class="ng-binding z3appRole-medium" type="text"
bo-class="'z3appRole-'+preferences._View._TileSize"
bo-style="{'color': DefaultRoleColor + ' !important'}"
bo-hide="preferences._View._TileSize == 'small'"
ng-bind="app._ShortRole" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">OCEANE - Gestion
des Tickets d'Incidents et Module Alerte</span>

<span class="app-event changeOpacity ng-hide icon-event-red"
data-original-title="Application unavailable" data-placement="bottom"
data-container="body" type="text" ng-click="showModalAppEvent(app)"
ng-class="getEventOnAppClass(app)"
ng-show="showEventOnApp(app)"></span> <span class="z3appBasicat"
bo-style="{'color': DefaultRoleColor + ' !important'}"
bo-bind="showTileCode(app._Code)" style="color: rgb(0, 0,
0);">21W</span> </div>
```

Comment: What part of html changes? `class` attribute inside `<div>`? What does it change to? Maybe there are some static parts which might be considerable to look for?

Comment: Can you update the question with some more of the _outerHTML_?

Comment: Can't you give the div a fixed id? You can retrieve by id, usually that's the best option for fixed elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try JavascriptExecutor along with cssSelector to click the element,

Refer code,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".z3tile.z3activeTile.z3-tile-medium"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

To know more about `JavascriptExecutor`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43394128/4047186).

Comment: Thanks Amit. Could you expalin how a normal click was different from this javaexecutor?